# How to check pub sub batch setting at publisher end really work as per configuration?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to the GCP world. I have to check whether my `batchSetting` for publishing message to pub sub really work or not. This is the batch setting:

```
 private BatchingSettings getBatchingSettings() {
        long requestBytesThreshold = 10000L;
        long messageCountBatchSize = 100L;
        Duration publishDelayThreshold = Duration.ofMillis(2000);
        BatchingSettings batchingSettings = BatchingSettings.newBuilder()
                .setElementCountThreshold(messageCountBatchSize)
                .setRequestByteThreshold(requestBytesThreshold)
                .setDelayThreshold(publishDelayThreshold)
                .build();
        return batchingSettings;
    }
```

I have to check whether pub sub publishes the message in batch of 100 or not.

Is there any way to check how many messages really published by per batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring) you can monitor Pub/Sub in Cloud monitoring. When you follow the link you will go to the Cloud Monitoring on your project.

In **Metrics explorer** its possible to create a metric of flowing configuration:

- Recourse type: `Cloud Pub/Sub Topic`
- Metric: `Publish message operations`
- Group by: `topic_id`
- Aggergator: `sum`
- Minimum alignment period: `1 minutes`

In "SHOW ADVANCED OPTIONS" set:

- Aligner: `sum`

If you search such chart in some dashboard you can check the count of published massages there. Now just submit separate testing batch and wait for peak on the chart. When you hoover on the chart line you will see the number of massages in particular time period. Sometimes it will be decided into more parts, but in such small batch like 100 it should be no more than 2. So its enough to add 2 numbers.

Of course you can create more sophisticated metrics. This is just example.